# Mapping db data to an Object using LINQ

Tags: c#, sql, linq, entity-framework-core, dbcontext

```
var studentDetails = _repository.Getdata(BatchId); // returns multiple data rows
Student stud_obj = new Student_obj();
```

> how can I map the stude_obj to var studentDdetails result using LINQ.

```
stud_obj.cs
 string name{get; set;}
 string class{get; set;}
 string rank{get; set;}
 string gender{get; set;}
```

Comment: what is `studentDetails` properties? and Is `studentDetails` type of class  list or not?

Comment: Please read [ask] and then edit this question to make it better.

Answer (score 2):

```
var studentDetails =
    _repository
        .Getdata(BatchId)
        .Select(x => new Student_obj
        {
            name = x.name,
            @class = x.@class,
            //etc
        }).ToList();
```

Comment: `class` by itself is not a valid identifier. You need the `@` sign in front of it.